# Are there any pitfalls to overriding ls?

Tags: ls, shell-builtin

Is there anything to watch out for if you wanted to override `ls`? Is there a more reliable way of getting pagination out of `ls`?

For example:

```
function ls() { command ls -hp $@ | more; }
```

Comment: You need to quote `"$@"`.

Answer (score 2):

No harm doing it your way as it may be scoped to interactive shells and not impact scripts.

Only danger (and it may be a big one if you work on wide range of systems) - you may get used to a habit of using a non-standard mapping unnecessarily.

Particularly with `ls` there are some established best practices in the industry.

E.g. many systems implement `ll` as a pagination variant of `ls`. It's easier to type and you can reasonably expect it to be already present in a new system you encounter.

To see which shortcuts are readily available to you type `alias` and `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use ls in a script ([don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), so that function will only be used by you in an interactive shell. Nothing to watch out for. Aside from adding double quotes around `"$@"`, that's the best way to do it.